# Remap apostrophe

Tags: templates, apostrophe

I am currently working on a LaTeX Template and I want to type the apostrophe with just typing in the code the symbol `'`, and to type the standard ' with the symbol `´`.

So in this way I'm able to type quotes and apostrophes with different symbol.

```
``Hello I'm Agente156´´
```

[image]

Currently, this apostrophe symbol that I want to replace can be expressed like: `\textsc{\char13}`. The code that I have to write now (awful):

```
``Hello I\textsc{\char13}m Agente156''
```

How can I remap the apostrophe and the tick to show those symbols? If possible without any `\newcommand{}`, as I don't want to write \' or \´ every time.

Comment: A typographically correct apostrophe (’, U+2019, RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) looks like a comma that is shifted up from the baseline. I don't know about your concrete set-up, but the default is already that you just type `'` to output this character. I think you should add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and also pictures of the glyphs that you are referring to.

Comment: Sorry, now you can see what I was refering to, although I don't know if it is even possibe to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am quite sure that this will break something since it makes `'` active (so it may be best to scope this somehow), but you could try with something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\catcode`\'=\active
\def'{\@ifnextchar{'}{{\textquotedblright}\@gobble}{\textquotesingle}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

``Hello I'm Agente156''

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would actually not recommend doing this and rather stick to the default (and typographically correct) way apostrophes are typeset, but maybe the above can help you find a more robust solution.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it, but to type `\textquotedblright` I want to type in LaTeX `´` (the tick instead of the backtick). I removed the `\@ifnextchar{'}{{\textquotedblright}\@gobble}` but I don't really know how to put `´` as `\textqutoedblright`. I tried adding the same code tweaking the neccessary, but the catcode (\catcode`\´=\active) sends me an error of invalid UTF-8 byte "B4

Comment: SOLVE IT! I used ChatGPT and he actually help out, wow. To do so I just wrote `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B4}{\textquoteright}`.

Comment: I guess, it should be possible to put ``\catcode`\'=\active \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0027}{\textquotesingle} \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B4}{\textquoteright}`` into your preable then. However, this approach with `\textquoteright` seems to work only because `\textquoteright\textquoteright` is obviously converted into `\textquotedblright`. Also, this still does not solve the possible issues arising from making `'` active.